# Facebook redirect ot url instead of playing swf

Tags: php, html, facebook, share

I have some strange issue with Facebook share. Im using the following code to share an swf player on Facebook. It shares the player, and its useable on Facebook, but only for me. For other users it only shares the preview image and clicking on it redirects to the url instead of append the player and play it.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="*****">
<meta property="og:title" content="Hallgassviccet"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="video"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.hallgassviccet.hu/index.php?id=1"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.hallgassviccet.hu/images/preview.swf?componentWidth=280&componentHeight=78&pathToFiles=http://www.hallgassviccet.hu/admin/player/&xmlPath=xml/settings.xml&artistName=Hallgass Viccet&songName=A szétvert budi&songURL=viccek/viccek_100907_a szetvert budi.mp3" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/H73O8zaHmAo/default.jpg">
<meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="280" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="78" />
```

And the share url is:

```
<a title="Add a Facebook-hoz" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.hallgassviccet.hu/index.php?id=1');return false;" href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="images/facebook.png" onMouseOver="this.src='images/facebook_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/facebook.png'" width="24" alt="Oszd meg Facebook-on" style="cursor:pointer;" /></a>
```

Whats wrong here? Why other people cant use the swf player on Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the others are logged in over HTTPS and you over HTTP. Facebook won't play back the SWF for users who are browsing over HTTPS unless the SWF source is over HTTPS as well.